# Why can't SQL Server Compact Edition open an existing SDF file if my connection string contains the max database size keyword?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I keep seeing this exception:

> ex = {"Keyword not supported: 'max database size'."}

When I try running the following code (exception is thrown on the LINQ query line):

```
LogContext l = new LogContext(connectionString);
var v = from log in l.Logs select log;
count += v.Count();
```

The `LogContext` class looks like this:

```
public class LogContext : DbContext
{
    public LogContext()
        : base()
    {
    }
    public LogContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<LogRecord> Logs { get; set; }
}
```

My connection string contains the `Max Database Size` property. Is there a reason why its throwing this exception? Does SQL Server Compact Edition use the `Max Database Size` property only once for creating the database and stores this information in the local file or something, such that I can't connect to this file when I specify this property thereafter? Because this all works when I create new databases.

Comment: Are you use the SQL Server Compact provider? You would get this error if you were using the SQL Server provider? Show your config...

Comment: Please mask out any userid/password and any public ip before posting your config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the DefaultConnectionFactory seemed to work for me:

> Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new
>   SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");

Comment: Can you please mention where to place this initialization? Should it be from constructor of Context class?

Comment: @YeasinAbedinSiam Considering how this was 6 years ago, I’m not entirely sure anymore. But, presumably before you create a connection to your SQL CE DB using the SqlCeConnection class, as the library uses the factory pattern. So, you are telling the factory how to produce the connections ahead of time.